# Gummy residue from baking spray/oil

Tags: baking, cleaning, oil

I'm sure everyone's seen this - that brownish stuff left behind when you grease an area of a baking dish that gets left exposed to the heat. Soap doesn't bother it too much, and it likes to gum up my scrubber. What's going on there, and are there any easy ways to get it off?

Comment: Your spray/oil is a drying or semi-drying oil. Switch to something less unsaturated, and your troubles will decrease: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_value I use mostly olive oil. Coconut, palm, canola or peanut oil would also work. Corn and soybean oils are disasters waiting to happen.

Comment: I see I've been here. The link is still good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When oil gets overheated, it turns into a polymer that is insoluble in water, even with soap.

The best way to clean this up is with [Barkeeper's Friend](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V72992), [Bon Ami](http://www.bonami.com/), or a similar solvent (I think they're all alkaline-based solvents). It's non-abrasive, and safe to use on almost all cookware without leaving marks.

Edit: To help prevent this from happening in the future, use a paper towel to wipe off any excess baking spray on the edges of the baking dish that won't be covered by food.

Comment: To expand on what Bob said -- basically, the oil polymerization is the exact process that you're *trying* to get when you season cast iron ... it just really sucks when it's all splotchy on your other pans.

Comment: Yeah, I know, best solution is not to let it happen - but sometimes you forget, or miss a spot. As for the cleaning tips, thanks - though I don't think alkalinity is the factor there. Wikipedia says Barkeeper's Friend's active ingredient is oxalic acid, while Bon Ami's listed active ingredients are sodium carbonate, calcium carbonate, and feldspar (described there as mild abrasives, though obviously alkaline too). I'm sure both work great though!

Comment: I probably sound like a broken record chiming in on every thread about cleaning, but I live and die by my Barkeeper's Friend!

Comment: Dunno about Barkeeper's Friend, but Bon Ami is, indeed, an abrasive. It's less likely to scratch than some other scouring powders that aren't milled as finely, but its primary cleaning action is still mechanical rather than chemical.

Comment: I just soak the pan in water for a day or two, which loosens it enough to scrub off without any other gunk.

Comment: not sure if it will work or not, but perhaps a soak overnight in a mild acid solution (like vinegar or lemon juice) would help.

Comment: Thanks to everyone chiming in - I'll definitely try acid soak in the future. This time I managed with just scrubbing and baking soda. (I try to avoid buying too many cleaning products, though the two mentioned here don't sound too nasty.)

Answer (score 4):

I used a Mr. Clean Magic Eraser last night on my deep fryer. It took a little elbow grease but it came right off, no chemicals needed

Comment: Don't just use them on everything: "Not recommended for the following surfaces: high gloss, polished, dark, brushed, satin, faux, bare/polished wood, copper, stainless steel appliances, non-stick coating or vehicle body. Rinse required for surfaces in direct contact with food." Source: https://www.mrclean.com/en-us/how-to/kitchen/clean-cakedon-casserole-pans

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any method for the burnt-on oil in particular, but for difficult to clean pans in general, I usually resort to razor blades (not cartridge ones though). Something like a proper scraper tool would be even better.

Basically, something **really** sharp that can get underneath the substance, and then it can't help but come off.

Chemically, I'm assuming the stuff left on the pan after the cooking process wouldn't be the oil, since that comes off in soap. I suspect (guessing here) that it's the propellant from the can. Which isn't really that much of a pleasant thought.

Comment: The same thing happens if you oil the pan the traditional way rather than using a spray, so it has nothing to do with the propellant.

Comment: A few years ago, I found that many hardware stores sell “plastic razor blades”. They’re sized to fit into standard razor blade holders, but less damaging, and often double sided.  I’ve gotten two types so far, and the yellow ones from Ace Hardware were sharper and stiffer than the black ones I got from a non-chain hardware store.  Also, Lodge sells a two-pack of plastic scrapers that work really well and have lots of curves on them to fit almost any pan edge they’re maybe $3-4, but way more online.

Answer (score 1):

I use baking soda. Wet the pan but don't leave water puddles in it. Poor on some baking soda and rub firmly over the affected area. Rinse well and enjoy the satisfaction of having removed that tough,gummy ick.

Answer (score 0):

Comet and a small scrub brush with a handle . I bought a wooden handle metal bristol small brush generally used to scrub  battery acid off  and use on my stainless steel pots and pans. I am sure it would work on glass too.

Answer (score 0):

Place your baking dish in a larger baking pan & squeeze soap dish over it plus a  couple of handfuls of baking soda then add hot water to cover the dirty baking dish. Let it soak for an hour of so then just scrub with a brush & that's it!

You can buy a large box of baking soda at Smart & Final or Sam's Club or Costco.
The baking soda will not scratch your baking dish.

Answer (score 0):

Plain oil painter's turpentine does the trick. Thins the oil, dissolves residue...discard excess liquid oil, apply turps with an old bristle type paint brush. Thick caked-on gunk (like an abused deep fryer) may take a couple of applications or soaking but unlikely to have to wait "overnight". Turps isn't gritty and gets in the finest cracks to displace plasticized oils so fine polished finish on stainless steel isn't blemished with scratches from grit based cleaning products. Wipe with paper towel.
Clean residual turps "smell" off appliance with any dishwashing detergent or methylated spirits for extra clean.